# jQuery animation on window load on an infinite loop?

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate

I need a hand making this code below working. I've had it working so that when the user hovers over the image it animates up, then down when losing focus, but now I want it to run on window load on an infinite loop.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.navImage').animate({top:'-=13'}, 700)
    }, function(){
        $('.navImage').animate({top:'+=13'}, 700);
    });
});
```

At the moment it's only animating 13pixels up, not down, and obviously the animation doesn't currently loop. Do I need to use some sort of callback?

Any help would be great, thanks.

[EDIT] Removed the height:toggle, didn't mean to include that.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about my old code, bit of an irrelevant comment from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function moveUp() {
    $('.navImage').animate({top:'-=13', height:'toggle'}, 700, moveDown);
}

function moveDown() {
    $('.navImage').animate({top:'+=13'}, 700, moveUp);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(moveUp);
});
```

=== UPDATE 1 ===

```
function move(jElem, bUp) {
    jElem.animate(
        {top: (bUp ? '-' : '+') + '=13'},
        700,
        function() {
            move(jElem, !bUp);
        }
    );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.navImage').each(function() {
            move($(this), true);
        });
    });
});
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yQVX/12/).

=== UPDATE 2 ===

Now they start with random delay:

```
function move(jElem, bUp) {
    jElem.animate(
        {top: (bUp ? '-' : '+') + '=13'},
        700,
        function() {
            move(jElem, !bUp);
        }
    );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navImage').each(function(iIndex, jElem) {
        // get random delay
        var iTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 700);
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                move($(jElem), true);
            },
            iTime
        );
    });
});
```

Also see my [jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3yQVX/15/).

=== Update 3 ===

And in this jsfiddle additional with random speed: [jsfiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/3yQVX/17/).

Comment: Hmmm, getting somewhere, thanks for this. Problem I'm getting is that it runs the function 'moveUp(') once then function 'moveDown()' 5x then the function 'moveUp()' 25x and so on... can't understand why it would do this though?

Comment: Nice. Is there an easy way of getting these to fire off at different/random times, so that the images aren't in synch?

Comment: You are welcome. If you keep this answer for the right one, it would be very nice if you would accept my answer.

Comment: Done. I'm new here, forgot about that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function anim_up() {
    $('.navImage').animate({top:'-=13', height:'toggle'}, 700, anim_down)
};
function anim_down() {
    $('.navImage').animate({top:'+=13'}, 700, anim_up);
};
window.onload = anim_up;
```

As a sidenote, you should replace that `navImage` class with an ID instead, if there's only one of them.

Comment: I have about 6 images that all need to be animated one after the other, but I'll worry about that later, will probably use a delay(). Thanks for your response.

Comment: I've got it working now, thanks both for your help, it was because I was using a class to animate and I had 5 objects using the same class name, using separate now IDs now and it works fine! Thanks again.

Comment: Spoke to soon... doesn't work when I try adding more than one ID.

Comment: IDs need to be unique. If you use the same ID twice, the code will only affect the first one.

Comment: Yeah I did, but I still had problems with it. Working with scessor's code now anyway.