# Clicking on the actual element to start an animation

Tags: jquery, animation

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="test">There I dont want put button</div>
```

and my CSS

```
#test { width: 300px; height: 100px; }
```

and the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#test").animate({height:300},"slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

How can I activate this animation without using a button? I want to click the div `#test` and animate it to 300x300. I tried using a link and a label, but it seems that the click handler only understands a button click.

Comment: See if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636103/jquery-animation-on-window-load-on-an-infinite-loop) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly assign the click event handler to div<sup>†</sup>:

```
$(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({height:300},"slow");
    });
});
```

Then when you click the div, the animation will start.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xThuL/)

Or if you want to run the animation directly when the page loaded, call the animation function directly:

```
$(function() {
    $("#test").animate({height:300},"slow");
});
```

---

†: Events related to user interaction such as `click`, `mouseover`, etc. work with **all** elements. But there are other events, such as `load` or `change`, which are only generated by certain elements.

Answer (score 1):

No, the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event can take any element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#test").click(function(){
    $("#test").animate({height:300},"slow");
  });
});
```

See a working demo :
http://jsfiddle.net/e4ceD/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#test').click(function(){
   $(this).animate({height:300},"slow");
});
```